# Is it possible to define a "not Nullable<T>" constraint in a C# generic method?

Tags: c#, generics, nullable, non-nullable, generic-constraints

In C#, the `Nullable<T>` type does not satisfy the `where` `struct` generic constraint (while AFAK this is techically a struct). This can be used to specify that the generic argument has to be a non-nullable value type :

```
T DoSomething<T>() where T : struct
{
   //... 
} 
DoSomething<int?>(); //not ok
DoSomething<int>();  //ok
```

And of course, `Nullable<T>` also does not satisfy the reference type `where` `class` constraint :

```
T DoSomething<T>() where T : class
{
   //...
} 
DoSomething<int?>(); //not ok
DoSomething<Foo>();  //ok
```

**Is this possible to define a constraint such as it has to be a reference type or a value type but not a Nullable value type ?**

Something like this :

```
void DoSomething<T>() where T : class, struct //wont compile!
{    
   //...   
} 
DoSomething<int?>(); //not ok
DoSomething<int>();  //ok
DoSomething<Foo>();  //ok
```

Comment: Everything but `Nullable<T>`? That is difficult.

Comment: Why do you want to do this?

Comment: As far as I know it is not possible with generic contraint, so there is no compile-time check available for this. You could however check the actual type at run-time.

Comment: You can sort of do it with overloads and optional parameters, but it's pretty nasty. See http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/11/02/evil-code-overload-resolution-workaround/ If you can give us more information about what you're trying to achieve, we can help you more.

Comment: @sloth : I have a `Add<TValue>(Func<TViewModel, TValue> expression)` method  and I'd like to make sure that is only used with non nullable types (eg :  `Add(x => x.Id)` OK `Add(x => x.CreationDate.Value)` OK `Add(x => x.CreationDate)` NOK ).

Comment: @tigrou - I think we understand that. We want to know what you're actually trying to do, not how you're trying to do it.

Comment: @tigrou But if you use a reference type (class) the value may also be null.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it's not possible on the declaration side. It's either `struct` OR `class`.
However, you can check the `typeof(T)` at run-time to ensure `T` is `Nullable<T2>`

```
Type type = typeof(T);
if(Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(type) == null)
    throw new Exception();
```

Answer (score 3):

As noted in a comment, you can do this with overloads *and* parameters (which can be optional). I [blogged about this](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/11/02/evil-code-overload-resolution-workaround/) a while ago, but in your case you'd want:

```
public class ClassConstraint<T> where T : class
{
}

public class SomeClass<TViewModel>
{
    public void Add<TValue>(Func<TViewModel, TValue> expression,
                            ClassConstraint<TValue> ignored = null)
        where TValue : class
    {
        AddImpl(expression);
    }

    public void Add<TValue>(Func<TViewModel, TValue> expression,
                            Nullable<TValue> ignored = null)
        where TValue : struct
    {
        AddImpl(expression);
    }

    // No constraints
    private void AddImpl<TValue>(Func<TViewModel, TValue> expression)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

It's ugly, but it works:

```
var z = new SomeClass<string>();
z.Add(x => x.Length);        // Valid (non-nullable value type)
z.Add(x => x);               // Valid (reference type)
z.Add(x => new DateTime?()); // Invalid (nullable value type)
```